# Retrieve all the Jpassword value in a Jtable

Tags: java

I am new to java.I have a requirement in which JTable is used.
Requirement is to create a JTable with 3 columns . 1st column is serial number, 2nd column is file name and the last one is password field. Once the user enters passwords for all of the files in the table and press ok, the logic should check the password entered for all of the files is correct . 
I have created table as per requirement but struck with iterating through password fields and get each password entered for further check. 
Can anyone have any idea on how to iterate through jpassword fileds and get the value one by one?

Comment: if you are new to Java, you should start by learning Java. "logic should check the ... is correct". and how would it check that?

Answer (score -1):

Create an array of `JPassword` fields and then iterate over it and fetch the passwords. Make sure you use `toString()` to get the text from the password field.

Comment: `toString()` is the wrong method to call here. Maybe you mean `getText()`, but it should be `getPassword()`, which returns a `char[]` instead of a `String`. That is always safer since `String`s are immutable, whereas `char`s aren't.

Comment: No problem. Please edit your answer to reflect what you meant :-)